Send multiple photos with text aiogram
I can send several photos like this:
group = []
for photo in photos2:
    group.append(InputMediaPhoto(media=photo))
await message.answer_media_group(group, caption="Text123", text='Text123')

But caption and text don't work
I can also send a photo with text but only one
await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=caption)
But I can't find how to send several photos with text
I looked at the aiogram documentation but didn't find the answer to my question.
How to do it?
aiogram 3.4.1

Try this one. Showing my example as reference:
from aiogram.utils.media_group import MediaGroupBuilder

@router.message(UploadPostAd.photos)
async def process_photos( message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Process the photos here
    if message.photo:
        photo_ids = get_all_photo_ids(message)  # Get all photo IDs

        media_group = MediaGroupBuilder(caption="Media group caption")
        for photo in photo_ids:
            media_group.add_photo(type="photo", media=photo)

        await message.answer_media_group(media=media_group.build())
        await state.clear()

